# Issue call webservice

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

Hi I am trying to communicate with a webservice in my asp.net page in my code behind (vb.net) when i make the call I get a 401 unauthorised error however when i try the same call though a simple html page it works.

here is my simple html page

```
     <form method="post" action="https://mycallingwebpage.co.uk/login">
     <input type="submit">
     </form>
```

this works fine and returns what i would expect.

however in my vb.net code this doesn't work.

```
 Public Function mylogin(ByVal ServiceProfile) As String
     Dim xmldoc As New Xml.XmlDocument
    Try
        myWebClient = New WebClient

        myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain")

       Dim bytRetData As Byte() = myWebClient.DownloadData("https://mycallingwebpage.co.uk/login" & ServiceProfile)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Function
```

---

I have now made some steps forward.

Further to my earlier question above i am still not able to make the call. I have found that if i make a call to the http url it works but calling the the https url it does not - this ajax call below does work for me - so effectively what do i need to do to convert this code below into a webclient call in vb.net?  - this needs to work for https

```
  $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              dataType: "application/xml",
              crossDomain: true,
              data: {'login' : encodeURIComponent('user'),'password' : encodeURIComponent('password')} ,
              url: "https://myURL.com",
              success: doThis,
              error: doThat
          });
```

Comment: what is `ServiceProfile`?

Comment: are you sure you aren't hiding the exceptions in your vb code?

Comment: Yeah, get rid of that try/catch block, very first thing.

Comment: the block catches the error so I can see its a 401 error - not sure what effect removing this will have?

Answer (score 0):

you have to "authorize" yourself before accessing the WS. You are probably missing an Authorization header. Sorry, I'm not much of a VB expert, but it should be something like this:

```
myWebClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + ADD_UR_SECRET_HERE)
```

BTW, don't forget to encode your secret token using a Base64 Encoder before adding it to the headers.

Hope it helped.